# creating a three level css accordion menu

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I have created a two level CSS accordion menu [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqGokUqU0IJW1zwUNxJe?p=preview). I am now trying to make an attempt to create a third level. I have slightly myself with the css nesting of the layer. The example below is how I assume it should be. Does anyone know the correct nesting method.

```
#main-nav li ul a:hover:before, .subMenu li ul a:hover:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: -0.75em;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: They open on mouseover, right? I might try `#main-nav li:hover > ul`

Comment: Yeah they open on mouseover

Comment: Ok that selector says: if I am in `#main-nav` and I am hoviering over a list item, give me the `ul` that is the immediate child. You can it then for show/hide

Comment: @Tim sorry i don't quite understand, can you demonstrate in jsFiddle

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Let me know If I can clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first at all you have this property:

> overflow:hidden

That hides your shape and let only the visual as an arrow but hides to the subsubmenu. You may need to find a shape that only draws the arrow.

Also you are setting

```
#main-nav ul li {
  position:relative;
}
```

Remove this and the subsubmenu can be the 100% `height` of the previous menu.

And on this selector:

```
 #main-nav li:hover  ul
```

Add the `>` to only affect the direct children `ul` of `#main-nav li` not all the ul inside:

```
#main-nav li:hover > ul
```

The demo **http://plnkr.co/edit/WAZplAWxzLieRZh1jNMa?p=preview**

*Edit*

You can see here how to obtain the [right arrow shape](http://www.css3shapes.com/) , check this new **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qivwRVRpGMVJ6eIyCsDL?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough proof of concept as a 'from first principles' approach to nested hovers:

http://jsfiddle.net/6X9NR/1/

```
 <ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">1.1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">1.1.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.2.2</a></li>
                </ul>            
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
</ul>
```

the css:

```
#main-nav ul {display:none}
#main-nav li:hover > ul {display: block}
```

The main part is with the last selector. It says any `ul` that is the direct child of a `li` that is being hovered over should be shown.

The first selector hides all submenus.

It is as simple as that for basic functionality. Modified, this should work with arbitrary positioning changes and css transitions if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

try this on line 61 change overflow (or remove it):

```
#main-nav li ul, .subMenu li:hover ul {overflow:hidden;}
```

to secure an overflow of left arrow at anchor hover just add overflow:hidden to taht anchor on line 71 in your CSS "style.css"

```
#main-nav li ul a, .subMenu li ul a {overflow:hidden;}
```

also remove position relative from your li elemnts, to align children ul's from top of parent ul
becouse you have a border-top on line 41, you would have to add this, to align all 3 ul's from top :

```
#main-nav ul ul ul {top:-1px}
```

Hope I didn't forgot anything.
Anyway your problem was only overflow :) other things are just cosmetic changes